# jQuery alert text in option from select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select code with two option.  Is there a way I can use jQuery to alert me the text within the option tag of the option I have selected?  Currently I have option two selected so when I use the code below it comes back as "5".  I need it to come back as "Option 2".

```
alert (jQuery('#bw_status').val());
```

The code below is the example code I am using.

```
<select id="bw_status">
<option value="7">Option 1</option>
<option value="5">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, try this:

```
jQuery('#bw_status option:selected').text()
```